# SQL transactions within a table older than date, but doesn't have any lately

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, self-join

I have two tables, InvMaster and InvMovements.  I need to find all movements older than x months, but limit to rows that have not had movements since x months. The primary date field is InvMovements.EntryDate

InvMovements is a collection of all the inventory transactions. The StockCode is unique of course in the InvMaster table with a 1 to many on the InvMovements.

Here is what I've put together so far.

```
SELECT Inv.StockCode, MAX(Inv.EntryDate) as EntryDt
FROM InvMaster AS IM 
LEFT JOIN InvMovements AS Inv 
  ON IM.StockCode = Inv.StockCode 
--This gets us all the rows that have had JX transactions in the last x months 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT IM.StockCode, MAX(IMv.EntryDate) As EntryDate 
            FROM InvMaster AS IM 
            LEFT JOIN InvMovements AS IMv 
              ON IM.StockCode = IMv.StockCode
            WHERE IMv.StockCode LIKE 'JX%' 
              AND IMv.EntryDate >= DATEADD(m, (-24), GETDATE())  
               OR IMv.EntryDate IS NULL
            GROUP BY IM.StockCode) AS MovedStock 
  ON MovedStock.StockCode != Inv.StockCode 
WHERE Inv.StockCode LIKE 'JX%' 
  AND Inv.EntryDate <= DATEADD(m, (-24), GETDATE()) 
   OR IM.StockCode LIKE 'JX%' AND Inv.EntryDate IS NULL
GROUP BY Inv.StockCode
```

Comment: Just to clarify, since you used x as a variable twice, do you want the older than variable and since variable to always be the exact same number?

Comment: you can do this with a where clause using `WHERE Inv.StockCode NOT IN (...select to get stockCodes with movement in since x months...)` or using `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you just need a NOT EXISTS in your WHERE condition.

i tried to clean up your where condition some, since it didnt make sense to me.

```
SELECT  IM.StockCode,
        MAX(Inv.EntryDate) AS EntryDt
FROM    InvMaster AS IM
        LEFT JOIN InvMovements AS Inv ON IM.StockCode = Inv.StockCode 
WHERE   IM.StockCode LIKE 'JX%'
        AND (Inv.EntryDate <= DATEADD(m,(-24),GETDATE())
                OR Inv.EntryDate IS NULL)
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    InvMovements AS MovedStock
            WHERE   IM.StockCode = MovedStock.StockCode
                    AND MovedStock.EntryDate >= DATEADD(m,(-24),GETDATE())
        )
GROUP BY IM.StockCode
```

Comment: Perfect... I really appreciate it. I've circled around this and used the Not Exist earlier today, but must have had some other things mucking it up.. Again, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want all movements with a JX stock code older than a certain number of months, but only if they haven't had an movement since a certain number of months. For this example it will give you movements older than 6 months (WHERE CLAUSE) but only if they haven't had a movement in the last 3 (HAVING CLAUSE). If you really want those numbers to always be the same just use the same variable.

```
DECLARE @olderThanMonths TINYINT = 6
    ,@sinceMonths TINYINT = 3

SELECT Inv.StockCode, MAX(Inv.EntryDate) as EntryDt
FROM InvMovements AS MO
    JOIN InvMaster AS MA
        ON MO.StockCode = MA.StockCode
WHERE MO.EntryDate <= DATEADD(MONTH,@olderThanMonths,GETDATE())
    AND MA.StockCode LIKE 'JX%'
GROUP BY Inv.StockCode
HAVING MAX(Inv.EntryDate) <= DATEADD(MONTH,@sinceMonths,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Anthony - your answer provided the same result I've been getting.. It did not work. JamieD77 answers hit the nail on the head.